# In a port from Three.js 68 to 69: Cannot read property 'boundingSphere' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, migration

I'm porting a project from Three.js v68 to v69 and am getting an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'boundingSphere' of undefined`on line 6077 of Three.js v69:

It's a function in the `THREE.Frustrum.prototype`:

```
intersectsObject: function () {
    var sphere = new THREE.Sphere();
    return function ( object ) {
        var geometry = object.geometry;
        if ( geometry.boundingSphere === null ) geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        sphere.copy( geometry.boundingSphere );
        sphere.applyMatrix4( object.matrixWorld );
        return this.intersectsSphere( sphere );
    };
}(),
```

**What has migrated here that I should pay attention to in my code?**

I'm switching from 68 to 69 in order to use several THREE scripts to do some postprocessing (THREE.EffectsComposer and others [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Instructables-Universe-in-Threejs/step12/Threejs-Post-processing-Effects-Dimming-Blurring/)). The scripts require the use of PlaneBufferGeometry now in 69 (perhaps among other things).

**UPDATE:**
Here's the stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'boundingSphere' of undefined Three_69_max.js:6077
(anonymous function) Three_69_max.js:6077
projectObject Three_69_max.js:21161
projectObject Three_69_max.js:21200
render Three_69_max.js:21035
animLoop.render AnimationLoop.js:161
animate MainBreederProgram.js:14
init MainBreederProgram.js:32
...
```

**UPDATE:**
Looking deeper into the call stack it appears that it's crashing when asking for the geometry of an `Object3D` in my scene. The `Object3D` is holding a set of other `Object3D`s and has no inherent geometry of its own - it's simply there as a matter of convenience so I can easily access the set of objects it contains.

Comment: `Frustum.intersectsObject( object )` requires the object to have a geometry.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - how do you give an Object3D a geometry? I tried using a Box3 based on .getBoundingBox

Comment: You don't. Pass only objects having a geometry to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @WestLangley's advice above I've shifted the organization of my code. Originally I'd been using Object3Ds to hold different sets of objects in the scene (through v68) - this way I could easily access them and iterate though a subset of the contents of the scene in the update phase of my animation. Now as of v69, I've now placed all these objects directly into the scene and named them instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of the scene graph's main functions would be to facilitate grouping of objects, so this behavior was odd to me and I was getting the same exception in r71.

Using a `THREE.Group` instead of a THREE.Object3D fixed the error for me.

Digging through the code, I found something undocumented called THREE.Group which inherits from THREE.Object3D. Groups don't appear to participate in the frustum check, but their children do (which is the behavior we want).